# How to detect if Azure Powershell session has expired?

Tags: powershell, authentication, azure

I'm writing an Azure PowerShell script and to login to Azure I call `Add-AzureAccount` which will popup a browser login window.

I'm wondering what's the best way to check if the authentication credentials have expired or not and thus if I should call `Add-AzureAccount` again?

What I now do is that I just call `Get-AzureVM` and see if `$?` equals to `$False`. Sounds a bit hackish to me, but seems to work. And does it still work if the subscription doesn't have any virtual machines deployed?

Comment: Johan Paul, if you're still out there, you ought to accept Aviad Ezra's answer...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to run Get-AzureRmContext and check if the Account property is populated. In the latest version of AzureRM, Get-AzureRmContext doesn't raise error (the error is raised by cmdlets that require active session). However, apparently in some other versions it does.

This works for me:

```
function Login
{
    $needLogin = $true
    Try 
    {
        $content = Get-AzureRmContext
        if ($content) 
        {
            $needLogin = ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($content.Account))
        } 
    } 
    Catch 
    {
        if ($_ -like "*Login-AzureRmAccount to login*") 
        {
            $needLogin = $true
        } 
        else 
        {
            throw
        }
    }

    if ($needLogin)
    {
        Login-AzureRmAccount
    }
}
```

If you are using the new Azure PowerShell API, it's much simpler

```
function Login($SubscriptionId)
{
    $context = Get-AzContext

    if (!$context -or ($context.Subscription.Id -ne $SubscriptionId)) 
    {
        Connect-AzAccount -Subscription $SubscriptionId
    } 
    else 
    {
        Write-Host "SubscriptionId '$SubscriptionId' already connected"
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm tracking this down but there's still some cases where Subscription.Id is populated but still require a login since Set-AzContext returns  Please provide a valid tenant or a valid subscription.

Answer (score 35):

Azure RM but this will check if there is an active account otherwise throw up a prompt.

```
if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($(Get-AzureRmContext).Account)) {Login-AzureRmAccount}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 10):

I'd make it a little simpler than what Peter proposed. Just insert these lines somewhere at the beginning of your script:

```
Try {
  Get-AzureRmContext
} Catch {
  if ($_ -like "*Login-AzureRmAccount to login*") {
    Login-AzureRmAccount
  }
}
```

Cheers,

Comment: Get-AzureRmContent is not always failing when login is needed.

Comment: Hi Aviad, Could you please elaborate on this. Have you got more than one subscription active? If `Get-AzureRmContext` is not failing, do you get an error later in your script when trying to access Azure resources?

Comment: This is solution does not appear correct.  The OP references Azure ASM and this solution is using ARM.  As of today logging in with Azure ARM will not allow Azure ASM cmdlets to work for users accessing a shared subscription.

Comment: I tried this and was not logged in. The Get-AzureRmContent did not fail. It returned my account as empty, though. The Answer from Mark Grills catches this and as far as I can tell will work better.

Answer (score 5):

I created a module that I use on my scripts for this. It uses the `Get-AzAccessToken` cmdlet.

```
function Get-AzLogin {
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS
            Checks AZ login status and account
        .DESCRIPTION
            Use this module to check Azure PowerShell login status and make sure that user is logged in.

            It also accepts either subscription name or ID to be set right after checking login.
        .EXAMPLE
            Get-AzLogin
        .EXAMPLE
            Get-AzLogin [[-Subscription] <string>]
    #>
    param (
        [string] $Subscription
    )

    Write-Host "[Get-AzLogin] Checking Azure PowerShell Login... " -NoNewline
    # Check if logged in to Azure PowerShell
    $AccessToken = Get-AzAccessToken -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if (!$AccessToken) {
        Write-Host "Login needed"
        try {
            Login-AzAccount -ErrorAction stop > Out-Null
        }
        catch
        {
            throw "Could not login to Azure"
        }
    } else {
            Write-Host "Already logged in"
    }

    # Try setting subscription if provided
    if ($Subscription) {
        Write-Host "[Get-AzLogin] Found subscription as argument. Will run Set-AzContext... " -NoNewline
        try {
            Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $Subscription -ErrorAction stop | Out-Null
            Write-Host "set to $((get-azcontext).Subscription.name)"
        }
        catch
        {
            throw "Could not set Subscription $Subscription"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
function Check-Session () {
    $Error.Clear()

    #if context already exist
    Get-AzureRmContext -ErrorAction Continue
    foreach ($eacherror in $Error) {
        if ($eacherror.Exception.ToString() -like "*Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login.*") {
            Add-AzureAccount
        }
    }

    $Error.Clear();
}

#check if session exists, if not then prompt for login
Check-Session
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works well for me, just try to select the subscription, if it errors, prompt for login:

```
Try
{
    Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName $SUBSCRIPTIONNAME -ErrorAction Stop
}
Catch{
    Add-AzureRmAccount
    Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName $SUBSCRIPTIONNAME
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the Azure context in a variable at the beginning of your script and check for the "Account" property as it is NULL when there is no active login.

```html
$context = Get-AzureRmContext
if($context.Account -eq $null)
{
    Login-AzureRmAccount
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can check the result of Add-AzureAccount operation

```
$result = Add-AzureAccount
if (!$result) {Write-Output "Login to Azure failed"}
else {Write-Output "Login successful - user $result.Id"}
```

Comment: I don't think it answers this particular question. It does answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28105128/how-to-detect-if-azure-add-azureaccount-login-fails-or-is-canceled and in fact I used similar code like yours to answer that question.

Comment: The answer here doesn't answer how I can know if the session is expired and thus if I have to show the login screen with Add-AzureAccount.