# How to detect if Azure Add-AzureAccount login fails or is canceled?

Tags: powershell, authentication, azure

In an Azure PowerShell script I use `Add-AzureAccount` to login the user to Azure. But how do I detect if the user didn't finish the login successfully so that I can abort the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a PowerShell expert (and hoping we would get better answers), but can't we do something like the following:

```
$a = Add-AzureAccount
If ($a)
{
    Write-Verbose "User logged in"
}
Else
{
    Write-Verbose "User not logged in"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! Not maybe as elegant as I had hoped for, but who cares if it works :)

Comment: :). BTW, I have already sought help from PowerShell experts on this and your other question so let's hope we get good answers for both!

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this is to use a try and catch block.

```
try {
    Add-AzureAccount -ErrorAction Stop
}

catch {
    Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
}

#Write the remaining script here
#Control won't come here unless the Add-AzureAccount was successful

Write-Verbose 'User logged in'
```

However, any Microsoft account would be able to login even if they don't have any subscriptions associated. So, here is a bit modified code.

```
try {
    $a = Add-AzureAccount -ErrorAction Stop
    if ($a.Subscriptions) {
        Write-Verbose 'User Logged in'
    } else {
        throw 'User logged in with no subscriptions'
    }
}

catch {
    Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
}

#Write the remaining script here
#Control won't come here unless the Add-AzureAccount was successful
```

Answer (score 1):

I use following function, and the key is using the -warningVariable which will capture if the user canceled the login screen on purpose or if the logged in user doesn't have any subscriptions attached. Just in case something is not captured I added an errorAction stop so the exceptions are also taken care of.
The script below also offers the chance to re-enter credentials in case the user made a mistake.

```
function LoginAzure
{         

    try 
    {

        $a = Add-AzureAccount -ErrorAction Stop -WarningVariable warningAzure -ErrorVariable errorAzure


        if ($warningAzure -ne "")
        {
            $continue = Read-Host "Following warning occured: " $warningAzure " Press 'R' to re-enter credentials or any other key to stop" 
            if ($continue -eq "R")
            {
                LoginAzure 
            }
            else
            {
                exit 1
            }
        }

    } 
    catch 
    {
        $continue = Read-Host "Following error occured: " $errorAzure " Press 'R' to re-enter credentials or any other key to stop" 
        if ($continue -eq "R")
        {
            LoginAzure 
        }
        else
        {
            exit 1
        }
    }
     
}
Import-Module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement\Azure\Azure.psd1"

LoginAzure
```